# Is 出くわす a 他動詞 that's intransitive?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

According to [a video on transitive/intransitive verbs](https://youtu.be/ELk1dqaEmyk), "Cure Dolly" states that whether a verb ends in す is "always" a reliable indicator on whether it is an "other-move" verb (他動詞):

> [image]

Yet according to [my dictionary](https://jpdb.io/search?q=%E5%87%BA%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8F%E3%81%99&lang=english#a), the verb 出くわす is *intransitive*:

> [image]

**Question:** Is this one of those rare situations where transitivity and "other-moveness" (他動詞) diverges, so that 出くわす is an 他動詞 but still intransitive? Or is Cure Dolly's rule just wrong?

Comment: Is it part of a pair?

Comment: I ask because the rule is about pairs. It doesn't make sense to discuss it with just one verb alone.

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure this verb has a pair? So in that sense maybe Cure Dolly's rule isn't wrong.

Comment: No, 出くわす doesn't have the other *出食う, for example. 食う/食わす follows the rule in the sense that 食わす(or くらわす) can take a を-phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That rule is mostly true, especially for simple verbs, but it's not always true. There are a few exceptional cases where what was originally a transitive verb is now interpreted as an intransitive verb.

One example is [暮らす](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%9A%AE%E3%82%89%E3%81%99), which is normally regarded as an intransitive verb today. According to 明鏡国語辞典, it was originally a transitive (or causative) version of [暮れる](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%9A%AE%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B), but something like "to make days end" eventually became an independent intransitive verb meaning "to live (a life)".

When it comes to compound verbs, there are quite a few intransitive verbs that end with す, including 踊り明かす, 泣きはらす, 鉢合わす and 怒り散らす.

As for 出くわす, I could not find any authoritative source regarding its etymology. But it may be related to 交はす【くわす】, which is a transitive verb meaning "to cross/exchange (something)" in classical Japanese (its modern equivalent is 交わす【かわす】). This may be another example of a verb that changed its transitivity while being used as a compound verb. Cure Dolly's rule is useful when you learn words, but this is not a rule recognized by an average Japanese person, and there is seldom a 100% correct rule in the world of vocabulary, anyway.

Comment: RE etymology: I asked [here](https://hinative.com/questions/23158271#answer-53607650) whether 出くわす is related to くわす, and people indicated that Kanji mismatches between 出会す and 喰わす indicated this couldn't be the case. I was able to find some usages of 出喰わす [here](https://jpdb.io/vocabulary/1337950/%E5%87%BA%E5%96%B0%E3%82%8F%E3%81%99/used-in) though, so maybe they are related?

Comment: I found the entry in the NKD [here on Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%87%BA%E4%BC%9A%E3%83%BB%E5%87%BA%E4%BA%A4-2065009).  Apparently the form でっくわせる shows up first in 1700 → でっくわす in 1732 → でくわせる in about 1800 → でくわす in 1824. Looks like the canonical kanji spellings are 出会せる・出交せる / 出会す・出交す. My local NKD copy's entry for でっくわせる includes the note （「くわせる」は合わせるの意）, but 合わせる is still transitive, I thought?  Curious.

Comment: @George くわす is not a verb recognized by modern Japanese speakers, so you should have asked about it using kanji. According to NKD, 食わす is just an ateji.